# Jsoup Selector Regex matching

Tags: java, regex, jsoup, selector

I want to get just the elements with this id pattern "answer-[0-9]*"

I'm using this regex in select `"div[id~=answer-[0-9]*]"`

The matching elements are:

```
<div class="post-text" id="answer-45881">
```

and

```
<div class="hidden modal modal-flag" id="answer-flag-modal45881">
```

What must I change to get only the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on example from [official tutorial](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

```
[attr~=regex]: elements with attribute values that match the regular expression; 
e.g. img[src~=(?i)\.(png|jpe?g)]
```

it looks like jsoup simply checks if attribute contains some *part* which can be matched  with regex (like in this example `.png` or `.jpg`), not if entire value of attribute is matched by regex.

To check if regex matches entire string you need to place [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) representing start of the string `^` and end of the string `$`.

Also instead of `*` you probably should use `+` if you want to make number part mandatory.

So try with `div[id~=^answer-[0-9]+$]`

Comment: When I read the docs I understood that matches the entire. Just coding to know that is to some part. Thanks, your solution works!

Answer (score 2):

The `*` operator means "zero or more" times so it will still match the second example. You need to use the `+` operator instead meaning "one or more" times. So, your syntax would be:

```
div[id~=answer-[0-9]+]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it searches id to contain this pattern, not to match.

```
"div[id~=answer-[0-9]*$]"
```

should work then.